# Why is it that RESTlet takes quite time to print the XML, sometimes

Tags: java, rest, restlet, restlet-2.0

I am implementing REST through RESTlet. This is an amazing framework to build such a restful web service; it is easy to learn, its syntax is compact. However, usually, I found that when somebody/someprogram want to access some resource, it takes time to print/output the XML, I use JaxbRepresentation. Let's see my code:

```
@Override
@Get
public Representation toXml() throws IOException {
    if (this.requireAuthentication) {
        if (!this.app.authenticate(getRequest(), getResponse())) 
        { 
            return new EmptyRepresentation(); 
        }
    }

    //check if the representation already tried to be requested before
    //and therefore the data has been in cache
    Object dataInCache = this.app.getCachedData().get(getURI);
    if (dataInCache != null) {
        System.out.println("Representing from Cache");
        //this is warning. unless we can check that dataInCache is of type T, we can
        //get rid of this warning
        this.dataToBeRepresented = (T)dataInCache;
    } else {
        System.out.println("NOT IN CACHE");
        this.dataToBeRepresented = whenDataIsNotInCache();
        //automatically add data to cache
        this.app.getCachedData().put(getURI, this.dataToBeRepresented, cached_duration);
    }

    //now represent it (if not previously execute the EmptyRepresentation)
    JaxbRepresentation<T> jaxb = new JaxbRepresentation<T>(dataToBeRepresented);
    jaxb.setFormattedOutput(true);
    return jaxb;
}
```

AS you can see, and you might asked me; yes I am implementing Cache through Kitty-Cache. So, if some XML that is expensive to produce, and really looks like will never change for 7 decades, then I will use cache... I also use it for likely static data. Maximum time limit for a cache is an hour to remain in memory.

Even when I cache the output, sometimes, output are irresponsive, like hang, printed partially, and takes time before it prints the remaining document. The XML document is accessible through browser and also program, it used GET.

What are actually the problem? I humbly would like to know also the answer from RESTlet developer, if possible. Thanks

Comment: but sometimes it really2 fast, like there's no process. pls help to let me know why.

Comment: Adam, could you precise which version you are using and if you are using the built-in HTTP connector or the Jetty extension

Comment: Jerome. I think it's not the fault of RestLet. I think it's JAXB's problem. if I comment jaxb.setFormattedOutput; it will be fine, no lagging.

Comment: I use everything built-in, all that is provided by the ZIP; no other external dependency in case of the Restlet things. Restlet 2.1.2

Comment: Actually, the lagging problem is still occurring.

Comment: The internal HTTP connector is not stable yet. Please try using org.restlet.ext.simple or org.restlet.ext.jetty to see if it makes a difference. Not sure it is due to JAXB